# CSS => dropdown content right to dropdown button

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

In my rails project I use a dropdown button with dropdown content that opens under my dropdown button. Everything works fine. Here is the code:

```css
.dropdown {
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropbtn {
  background-color: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 160px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  font-size: 12pt;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #355264 !important;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ffb465 !important;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
          <div class="dropbtn"><%= image_tag("imprint.png") %></div>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <%= link_to I18n.t('basic.sign_out'), destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
            <%= link_to I18n.t('basic.friends'), fb_user_friends_path, :remote => true %>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Is it possible to position the dropdown content right to the dropdown button and how?

Thanks for help

Comment: is this something you want done ? https://jsfiddle.net/j19chpm8/1/

Comment: Yes but the dropdown content should be on the right of the word sample, not on the left.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j19chpm8/3/ check this out @Lars

Comment: That works generally. Problem is: In my project i have two or more fields of dropdown-content. The white background and shadow is the just behind the first one. The second background is transparent.

Comment: I found the answer: I left out 'bottom:0; margin:auto;' and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: oh I see good thing you did that you update the fiddle I gave you then thats cool explain it more in detail next time

Answer (score 1):

Add `right: 20px;` to your `.dropdown-content`. It should be equal to `.dropdown`'s right padding (20px in your case).

```css
.dropdown {
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 200px;
}
.dropbtn {
  background-color: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 160px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size: 12pt;
  right: 20px; /* added */
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #355264 !important;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ffb465 !important;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropbtn">Toggle</div>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    dropdown-content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had to use a negative value and 'top: 0px;'. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the drop down content right side just use  text-align:right; to .dropdown-content class like below

```
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: white;
min-width: 160px;
white-space: nowrap;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
font-size: 12pt;
text-align:right;
```

}

Comment: No. My point is not having the text-align right. I want to have the content right to the button and not under the button.

Comment: if you meant that the drop-down needs to be right, you can give right:20px to .dropdown-content class

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had to use a negative value and 'top: 0px;'. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for your help. Finally I added:

```
right: -145px;
top: 0px;
```

to my **dropdown-content**. That's it. Now it works.